# R: Filtering on the basis of row data

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this-

```
df <- structure(list(Category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"D", "D"), Subcategory = c("A_1", "A_2", "A_3", "B_1", "B_2", 
"C_1", "C_2", "D_3", "D_4"), Option = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", 
"Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Results of `df` :

```
  Category Subcategory Option
1        A         A_1     Q1
2        A         A_2     Q2
3        A         A_3     Q3
4        B         B_1     Q4
5        B         B_2     Q5
6        C         C_1     Q6
7        C         C_2     Q7
8        D         D_3     Q8
9        D         D_4     Q9
```

I want the output as such the data gets filtered based on `Category` basis . Like when I select `"A"`, the output should be:

A_1
A_2,
A_3.

and when I select `A_1`, I get `Q1`.

and subsequently for all categories.

Comment: Where are you using the code? Do you want subset of data based on the pattern? Like this `subset(df, grepl('A', Sub_category))` ?

Comment: I am trying to use this in the form creation. Actually, I want to create a sequential flow of the data.

Comment: Cascading filters perhaps you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncertain of whether I understand your application correctly, but usying dplyr the following could perhaps be what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(Category == 'A') %>% 
  pull(var = SubCategory)

df %>% 
  filter(SubCategory == 'A_1') %>% 
  pull(var = Option)
```

I created the data below to explore.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Category = c(rep('A', 3), rep('B', 2), rep('C', 2), rep('D', 2)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  mutate(SubCategory = paste0(Category, '_', row_number())) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Option = paste0('Q', row_number()))
```

***Edit***

You can make a function, that does what I understand you are interested in. The below is a quick and dirty approach. Probably you may find something more elegant or better tailored to your needs.

Hope it helps pointing you in the right direction.

```
showQuestions <- function(df, userCategory) {
  subcategories <- df %>% 
    filter(category == userCategory) %>% 
    pull(var = subCategory)
  
  print(paste0('Showing sub categories for ', userCategory, ': '))
  if (length(subcategories) == 0) {
    print('No sub categories for this category')
  } else {
    for (sc in subcategories) {
      print(paste0('Showing questions for sub category ', sc, ': '))
      questions <- df %>% 
        filter(subCategory == sc) %>% 
        pull(var = Option)
      if (length(questions) == 0) {
        print('No questions for this subcategory')
      } else {
        for (q in questions) {
          print(q)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# Try out e.g.
showQuestions(df, 'A')
showQuestions(df, 'E')
```

Comment: Actually I have a Question series, consisting of Categories, Sub-Categories, Questions and their relevant answers. I want to show the user Categories first, which when selected, shows its relevant Sub-category. When the sub-Category is selected, it shows the relevant Question and it's answer. Most importantly, when 1st question is finished, automatically next question is shown with relevant answer and it continues till the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` as needed (# optional row)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
  # filter(Category == "A")
  filter(Category == "A", Subcategory == "A_1")
```

data:

```
df <- tribble(
~Category, ~Subcategory, ~Option,
"A", "A_1", "Q1", 
  "A", "A_2", "Q2", 
  "A", "A_3", "Q3", 
  "B", "B_1", "Q4", 
  "B", "B_2", "Q5", 
  "C", "C_1", "Q6", 
  "C", "C_1", "Q7", 
  "D", "D_3", "Q8", 
  "D", "D_4", "Q9")
```